# MonetDB BEFORE INSERT TRIGGERs are just not working and I need some hlep to sort it out

Tags: triggers, monetdb

in the MonetDB docs there is a simple "AFTER UPDATE" trigger example:

https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/Triggers

That one works, but I tried to change this to a BEFORE INSERT, and FOR EACH ROW:

create the table:

`CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, name VARCHAR(1024));`

Insert some values:

`INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(10, 'monetdb');`

`INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(20, 'monet');`

create the trigger:

`CREATE TRIGGER 
   test5
BEFORE INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(4, 'update_when_statement_true');`

Insert some stuff to check the trigger functionality:

`INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t1;`

Select some stuff to see what happened:

`SELECT * FROM t1;`
Results:

`+------+---------+
| id   | name    |
+======+=========+
|   10 | monetdb |
|   20 | monet   |
|   10 | monetdb |
|   20 | monet   |
+------+---------+`

So basically nothing happened that I can tell with the trigger.
I have tried all kinds of things in the trigger like BEGIN ATOMIC...END, calling a procedure that inserts that row, using functions and nothing I find has worked.

What the bad part is is that this is not even close to what I want to accomplish with a before insert trigger, this is just seeing if I can get it to work.
The thing I really want to do is catch a row and insert it into another table if I don't like some of the values.
I do this in postgres already, and I am evaluating if MonetDB can give me similar functionality.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx. It seems like a bug. The trigger is properly called when inserting a single row.
Please sent the full report to info@monetdb.org and individual cases to the bugtracker.